# How to find out if the direction (your location and destination) is going north or south? (Android)

Tags: android, google-maps

As the title itself, how can I determine programmatically in android if the users location and destination is going North or South?

[image]

As for example, if the user inputted his location as Oslob and destination is Cebu City, I should display the bus going to North. And if the user's location is City of Naga and destination is Moalboal, I should display the bus going to South.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- first, based on your latLng position and latLng destination, for this case you can try to use SphericalUtil class from android-maps-utils, this is the link to  - [doc](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/SphericalUtil.html) , I think you need computeHeading method.
- Another option based on your magnetometer from device sensors, this [link](https://google-developer-training.gitbooks.io/android-developer-advanced-course-practicals/unit-1-expand-the-user-experience/lesson-3-sensors/3-2-p-working-with-sensor-based-orientation/3-2-p-working-with-sensor-based-orientation.html).